# systemd error message : Failed to start LVM event activation on device 253:0

Tags: linux, systemd, luks, lvm2

I have an Acer Notebook with Debian Linux 10.0.  As may be seen from `lsblk` output below, root partition is on 256GB SSD at /var/home and SWAP is located on an LVM2 volume located on two LUKS encrypted magnetic disks using the same passphrase.

```
$ lsblk

NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─sda1           8:1    0 465,8G  0 part  
  └─sda1_crypt 253:0    0 465,8G  0 crypt 
    ├─vg1-var  253:1    0  29,8G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─vg1-swap 253:2    0  29,8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─vg1-home 253:4    0 698,8G  0 lvm   /home
sdb              8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─sdb1           8:17   0 465,8G  0 part  
  └─sdb1_crypt 253:3    0 465,8G  0 crypt 
    └─vg1-home 253:4    0 698,8G  0 lvm   /home
sdc              8:32   0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sdc1           8:33   0   953M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sdc2           8:34   0 237,6G  0 part  /
```

Now, during boot I get some error messages from systemd and lvm2 as listed below, regarding that the second LUKS volume sdb1_crypt is somehow not recognized.  Regardless of this, at the end of the boot sequence the /home directory is fully functional as may  be seen:

```
$ sudo lvdisplay --maps /dev/vg1/home

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                cbSU7i-SYH9-9yeZ-pJdH-El6y-vhcS-YXtZfa
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time helium, 2017-07-28 05:49:15 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <698,81 GiB
  Current LE             178895
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4
   
  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 95366:
    Type        linear
    Physical volume /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
    Physical extents    7629 to 102995
   
  Logical extents 95367 to 103974:
    Type        linear
    Physical volume /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
    Physical extents    110625 to 119232
   
  Logical extents 103975 to 178894:
    Type        linear
    Physical volume /dev/mapper/sdb1_crypt
    Physical extents    0 to 74919
```

The error messages during boot are the following:

```
$ journalctl -b | grep -i lvm

Feb 17 09:13:48 helium systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium systemd[1]: Created slice system-lvm2\x2dpvscan.slice.
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium systemd[1]: Starting LVM event activation on device 253:0...
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium lvm[365]:   Couldn't find device with uuid a1qARu-SYG3-V61F-PqCo-0gyP-FkXI-JwfQ1A.
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium lvm[365]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1" monitored
Feb 17 09:13:47 helium systemd-udevd[384]: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules:40 Invalid value for OPTIONS key, ignoring: 'event_timeout=180'
Feb 17 09:13:47 helium systemd-udevd[384]: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules:40 The line takes no effect, ignoring.
Feb 17 09:13:48 helium lvm[484]:   Couldn't find device with uuid a1qARu-SYG3-V61F-PqCo-0gyP-FkXI-JwfQ1A.
Feb 17 09:13:49 helium lvm[484]:   Cannot change VG vg1 while PVs are missing.
Feb 17 09:13:49 helium lvm[484]:   Consider vgreduce --removemissing.
Feb 17 09:13:49 helium lvm[484]:   Cannot process volume group vg1
Feb 17 09:13:49 helium systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@253:0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
Feb 17 09:13:49 helium systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@253:0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 17 09:13:49 helium systemd[1]: Failed to start LVM event activation on device 253:0.
Feb 17 09:13:55 helium lvm[737]:   3 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1" now active
Feb 17 09:13:50 helium systemd[1]: Starting LVM event activation on device 253:3...
Feb 17 09:13:51 helium systemd[1]: Finished LVM event activation on device 253:3.
Feb 17 09:38:12 helium sudo[196131]:      jan : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jan ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status lvm2-pvscan@253:0
Feb 17 09:40:26 helium sudo[215910]:      jan : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jan ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl restart lvm2-pvscan@253:0
Feb 17 09:40:26 helium systemd[1]: Starting LVM event activation on device 253:0...
Feb 17 09:40:26 helium lvm[215913]:   3 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1" now active
Feb 17 09:40:26 helium systemd[1]: Finished LVM event activation on device 253:0.
Feb 17 09:45:09 helium systemd-udevd[384]: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules:40 Invalid value for OPTIONS key, ignoring: 'event_timeout=180'
Feb 17 09:45:09 helium systemd-udevd[384]: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules:40 The line takes no effect, ignoring.
```

At the end of boot process I do  have one service `lvm2-pvscan@253:0.service` related to `sdb1_crypt` that failed.  It can be manually restarted.

I should mention that the UUIDs ot sda1_crypt and sdb1_crypt are both included in /etc/cryptsetup.

You may rightfully ask why I worry when it is working ?  Well, I like to have a clean boot log without error messages to the extent possible, and maybe learn something about the boot process.  So if someone can tell me how to fix it, I'd be glad.  I think it may be related to the order of systemd actions but my knowledge is not sufficient to figure out what to do :-)

Comment: DId you find out what "Cannot change VG vg1 while PVs are missing." refers to (PV UUID a1qARu-SYG3-V61F-PqCo-0gyP-FkXI-JwfQ1A)?

Comment: No. I never found out.  I live with it.

Comment: so maybe delete the question as nobody will be able to answer.